# Navigate To Create-Contact-View in UWP

Tags: c#, contacts, windows-10, uwp

Is there a possibility to navigate from my Windows 10 UWP App to the Create-Contact-View of the people Hub?
So that the user can insert name, phone number, email (etc) and then save the contact.
In WP8 / Silverlight, there was the [SaveContactTask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.tasks.savecontacttask(v=vs.105).aspx) class to achieve this. There should also be the possibility to predefine some fields.

What I tried, was to use the [Launcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt187315.aspx), but there's no option to access the CreateContact-View.
I tried also to use the equivalent class of the SaveContactTask, which is the StoredContact class, but had no success.

I don't want to create the contact programmatically if there's another possibility.

Comment: No. You have to create your own UI.

Answer (score 0):

To get an overview of what is possible today with contacts, take a look at the `ContactManager class` the definitions is on MSDN here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.contacts.contactmanager.aspx

For a full Microsoft example just take a look here 
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/ContactCards

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know the sample and also the ContactManager class, unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem. So I think I'll have to create my own UI as Alan Yao said.

Comment: Shame you lost some functionallty from wp8 :/